# How to attach load handler to dynamically created items

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to bind a load handler to a dynamically created object (backbone view in my production code). I tried to use the approach outlined in [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements#_=_), and it works for a click handler but not a load handler. Does anyone know how to solve this?

This works (with click handler)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "img", function(){
      console.log("foo");
    });

    create();
  });

  function create(){
    $img = $("<img />").attr("src", "http://www.pureweber.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/jquery_icon.png");
    $("body").append($img);
  }
```

But this doesn't (with load handler)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("load", "img", function(){
      console.log("foo");
    });

    create();
  });

  function create(){
    $img = $("<img />").attr("src", "http://www.pureweber.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/jquery_icon.png");
    $("body").append($img);
  }
```

Comment: You can't. The load registers to the body, and the load event does'nt bubble that far, in fact it does'nt bubble at all.

Comment: That is useful information, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the usage of `on` with a subselector only works with event types that bubble up. The DOM `load` event does not bubble up the tree, so it will never reach `body` where you are listening for it.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

You will need to manually attach the handler to any images you create.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body img").on("load" onLoad);

  create();
});

functon onLoad(){
    console.log("foo");
}

function create(){
  $("<img />")
    .on('load', onLoad)
    .attr("src", "http://www.pureweber.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/jquery_icon.png")
    .appendTo('body');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there any way I can attach a load handler to a dynamically created image then?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I will manually attach a load handler then!